# How to get class method to update dictionary?

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to make a flexible argument parser which takes strings, finds arguments within them and creates a dictionary like this:

```
message = "--mass=12"
physics = comparse(message, "mass", "int", 10, "this is your mass attribute")
```

Produces: `{'mass': 12}`

I'm unable to update and add more arguments/keys (like if I wanted to add a 'vel' variable) to the dictionary. Unfortunately, I'm new to Python classes and although the parser detects the first argument, I'm unable to add to the dictionary. Here's my program:

```
import shlex
class comparse(object):
    def __init__(self, message, attribute, var_type, default, help_txt):
        self.data = {}   #This is the "data" dictionary that this function will ultimately return.
        self.message = message
        self.attribute = attribute
        self.var_type = var_type
        self.default = default
        self.help_txt = help_txt

        #Remove unwanted symbols (e.g. "=", ":", etc.)
        self.message = self.message.replace("=", " ")
        self.message = self.message.replace(":", " ")
        self.args = shlex.split(self.message)

    def parse(self):  
        try:
            options = {k.strip('-'): True if v.startswith('-') else v
                for k,v in zip(self.args, self.args[1:]+["--"]) if k.startswith('-') or k.startswith('')}
            if (self.var_type == "int"):
                self.data[self.attribute] = int(options[self.attribute])   #Updates if "attribute" exists, else adds "attribute".
            if (self.var_type == "str"):
                self.data[self.attribute] = str(options[self.attribute])   #Updates if "attribute" exists, else adds "attribute".  
        except:
            if self.attribute not in self.message:
                if (self.var_type == "int"):
                    self.data[self.attribute] = int(self.default)   #Updates if "x" exists, else adds "x".
                if (self.var_type == "str"):
                    self.data[self.attribute] = str(self.default)   #Updates if "x" exists, else adds "x".
        return self.data

    def add_argument(self):
        self.data.update(self.data)

message = "-mass: 12 --vel= 18"

physics = comparse(message, "mass", "int", 10, "this is your mass attribute")
comparse.add_argument(message, "vel", "int", 10, "this is your velocity attribute")
print (physics.parse())
```

The `comparse.add_argument` method doesn't work. There's obviously something I'm doing wrong and classes generally confuse me! Could someone point out what's wrong with my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused about how your class is designed. I've answered the question in a more holistic way, with suggestions about how you should maybe redesign your class to achieve your goal better.

Typically, when you initialize a class (your parser) you pass it all the data that it needs to do its work. It seems, however, like your goal is to create a generic physics parser `physics = comparse()` then add possible arguments like mass and velocity to the physics parser's data. You then give the physics parser a message string like `message = "-mass: 12 --vel= 18"` for which it should parse and extract the arguments. This would suggest that the end of your code snippet, which is currently

```
message = "-mass: 12 --vel= 18"

physics = comparse(message, "mass", "int", 10, "this is your mass attribute")
comparse.add_argument(message, "vel", "int", 10, "this is your velocity attribute")
print (physics.parse())
```

should look like so:

```
message = "-mass: 12 --vel= 18"

# create a parser
physics = comparse()
# tell the parser what arguments it should accept
comparse.add_argument("vel", "int", 10, "this is your velocity attribute")
comparse.add_argument("mass", "int", 10, "this is your mass attribute")    
# give the parser a specific message for which it should extract arguments
print (physics.parse(message))
```

This code snippet would create a parser, tell the parser what sorts of arguments it should accept (like velocity and mass), and then extract those arguments from a specific string `message`.

This design adheres better to object oriented programming principles. The benefits here are that you're creating a `physics` parser that can be reused, and then asking it to parse strings which it does not save in its own properties (no `this.message`). This way, you can make additional calls like `physics.parse("--mass: 40 --vel=15") and reuse the physics parser.

If this design fits your intention more accurately, I would modify the code in the following ways to adhere to it:

- modify your **init** function so that it takes no parameters.
- Since you have multiple arguments that you are storing within your
  class, instead of having `self.attribute, self.var_type, self.default, self.help_txt` be just single variables, I would make them arrays that you can add the attribute names, variable types, defaults, and help texts to for EACH argument. Initialize each of these as empty arrays in **init** like so: `self.defaults = []`. I would also change the name of each to indicate that they're arraysand not individual variables, so defaults, types, texts etc.
- Modify add_argument to be the following:

  def add_argument(self. attribute, var_type, default, help_txt):
          self.attributes.append(attribute)
          self.var_types.append(var_type)
          self.defaults.append(default)
          self.help_txts.append(default)
- Modify parser to take `message` as a parameter, remove its unwanted
  symbols, perform the split, and then execute its logic for each of
  the arguments you set up in add_argument.

Please comment if you have any questions, good luck!

Comment: Wow! I was thinking about that but I didn't know how to do it! You're very clever - guess that's why you're at Harvard! Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: you're very kind, I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

in the following code from what you gave

```
def add_argument(self):
        self.data.update(self.data)
```

the `add_argument` does not take any arguments.But, you have done the fllowing

```
comparse.add_argument(message, "vel", "int", 10, "this is your velocity attribute")
```

where you have given multiple arguments. this is the cause of the problem

To fix it, try modifying the add_argument function to accept the parameter's you want it to handle

EDIT: based on your comment, the function should have been

```
def add_argument(self,message, attribute, var_type, default, help_txt):
    data = comparse.parse(message, attribute, var_type, default, help_txt) 
    self.data.update(data)
```

But, here again, parse method is actually taking no arguments in your code, so..modify it to accept all the arguments you need along with self

Comment: I tried doing this:                                                                                                     def add_argument(message, attribute, var_type, default, help_txt):
        data = comparse.parse(message, attribute, var_type, default, help_txt)
        self.data.update(data) But its states there are too many positional arguments for an unbound method call.

Comment: "self" should always be the first argument. so, along with what you mentioned add self as the first parameter and try